# What does it mean that Elasticsearch does not store values?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a part of the Elasticsearch's document for `store` option of `text` type:

> By default, field values are indexed to make them searchable, but they
> are not stored. This means that the field can be queried, but the
> original field value cannot be retrieved.

I don't understand what does it mean by *fields are not stored by default*. How is this possible? I'm sure that I'm missing something here.
Can someone explain it in plain English to me?

[link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's suppose if you want to store `hello world in Elasticsearch` in `title` and want to come that in search result, when you search with any word in the title for example : `hello` or `world` or `Elasticsearch`.. than you need to have tokens of these search term in Elasticsearch [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/documents-indices.html#:%7E:text=Elasticsearch%20uses%20a%20data%20structure,documents%20each%20word%20occurs%20in.)..

By default, all Elasticsearch text fields goes through [text analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html)(that creates the tokens(world in plain english) for the input text).

Now in our example, given title would generate below tokens, that you also verify urself using below  API

```
GET http://es:9200/_analyze

{
    "text" : "hello world in Elasticsearch",
    "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

**And resultant tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "hello",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "world",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "in",
            "start_offset": 12,
            "end_offset": 14,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "elasticsearch",
            "start_offset": 15,
            "end_offset": 28,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Now store means the complete string aka (not tokenized) `hello world in Elasticsearch` of a field which is not useful for full-text search and as explained in Elasticsearch article stored **by default** as part of `_source`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have no idea where can storing the complete string be helpful. Would give an example?

Comment: And does it mean that every time we get a document containing a text, Elastic will concatenate all tokens in order to reproduce the text?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi reg1, it will be useful when you want to perform aggregation as it requires the complete string and reg 2) no Elasticsearch already has the complete string and tokens are produced from that string so it doesn't have to again `concatenate` the tokens to produce the original text, also tokens generated based on multiple criteria and can change/delete the words from original string. Hope this helps